# Applescript Convert Word doc to docx

Tags: applescript, ms-office

I am looking for a way to batch-convert/bulk-convert `.doc` files into `.docx` files. I found this [TidBITS Talk](https://talk.tidbits.com/t/batch-convert-doc-to-docx/8278) that references a [Redit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/applehelp/comments/3qd9az/applescript_to_batch_convert_doc_to_docx/cwe87hu/) for an AppleScript (AS) and a [dead DropBox link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/32g4s78ilb646i7/doc%20to%20docx%20converter.zip?dl=0) for an Automator integration of mentioned AS in a WorkFlow.

However, when I run the script in *Automator* or *Script Editor* I get a **Syntax Error** - **Expected end of line, etc. but found identifier.** Inside the script `compatibility` is highlighted (as being the issue, I guess).

What can be done to correct the error?

Find the new version as suggested by @CJK of the entire script here below:

```
property theList : {"doc"}

on run {input, parameters}
        set output to {}
        tell application "Microsoft Word" to set theOldDefaultPath to get default file path file path type documents path
        repeat with theDoc in input
        tell application "System Events"
            set theFolderPath to the path of theDoc's container
            set theExtension to name extension of theDoc
            set theName to name of theDoc
        end tell
        if theExtension is in theList then
            set l to the length of theName
            set exl to the length of theExtension
            set n to l - exl - 1

            set theFilename to (text 1 through n of theName) & ".docx"

            tell application "Microsoft Word"
                set default file path file path type documents path path theFolderPath
                open theDoc
                set theActiveDoc to the active document
                save as theActiveDoc file format format document file name theFilename without maintain compatibility
                close theActiveDoc
            end tell

            set end of output to the POSIX path of (theFolderPath & theFilename)
        end if
        end repeat

        tell application "Microsoft Word" to set default file path file path type documents path path theOldDefaultPath
        return output
end run
```

Find here below a screenshot of Script Editor after compilation without the word `compatibility` (trying to compile the code with this word gives me the same error message as the one at the beginning of this post):
[image: Screenshot of Script Editor after compiling the code.]

---

System used:

- macOS Catalina 10.15.5
- MacBook Pro (13", 2019, 2.8 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i7, 16 GB RAM, Intel Iris Plus Graphics 655 1536 MB)
- Microsoft Word Version 16.39 (20071300)
- Script Editor Version 2.11 (208)
- Automator Version 2.10 (492)

Comment: For one, you've nested multiple `tell application` blocks inside each other. That's asking for trouble. Separate them out into distinct blocks. It may or may not solve your issue, but it'll definitely prevent other ones from arising that might otherwise.

Comment: @CJK: thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I am not a programmer and I don't know how to do that. I found the code on the web and just tried to use it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Here you go: [https://paste.ee/p/5Zebi](https://paste.ee/p/5Zebi)

Comment: A quick way to diagnose the problem will be seeing how Script Editor renders the script just after you compile it (by pressing ⌘⃣ +  K⃣  or clicking the spanner button).  If you screenshot your Script Editor window just after you compile the script, being sure to get the entire script in view, you can add the screenshot to your post by clicking the [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/399252/edit) button.  I have a suspicion what the problem _might_ be, but seeing the compiled script will tell me for sure.

Comment: @CJK: thank you for the script.

I pasted it into Script Editor, however when I run it (or try to compile it) the error remains the same as with the multiple-nested `tell application`: "Syntax Error, Expected end of line, etc. but found identifier." and the word `compatibility` is highlighted.

Comment: Not surprising, it wasn’t intended to be a solution to your present issue, but it is nonetheless a necessary (or very recommended) reformulation of your script purely to separate the relevant commands into separate tell blocks, intended only for a particular application. Any headway on the screenshot ?  I wouldn’t pay too much attention to what’s being highlighted, except to assume it’s probably not that.

Comment: @CJK: yes, you are totally right regarding reformulation of the script and I thank you again. Regarding the screen shot, I could do it, but the script would not compile (either by pressing ⌘⃣ + K⃣ or clicking the spanner button which, I gather, is the same thing). I get the same error message as when I try to run it (or clicking the Play button): "Syntax Error, Expected end of line, etc. but found identifier." and the word `compatibility` is highlighted. Nevertheless, I tried without the word `compatibility` and there I get no error message. However, nothing happens.

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot––it wasn't what I thought it was.  But for a total stab in the dark, what about trying `without maintaining compatibility` (grasping at straws here, since `without maintain compatibility` may or may not be a syntax error in AppleScript, but it is very much a syntax error in the English language, so maybe it's missing an _`-ing`_).  If that doesn't work, then I'll tell you how you can script a one-line solution to do what this script is meant to be doing, which just popped into my head yesterday.

Comment: @CJK: I tried that as suggested, but the error remains the same (i.e., the same error message and `compatibility` is highlighted). However, in Microsoft Word, when I try to save a `.doc` file as `.docx`, there is a checkbox that reads `Maintain compatibility with previous versions of Word`. Perhaps this info may be of some use?


Wow! Would you have a one-line solution to batch/bulk-convert `.doc` files into `.docx` files, that would be amazing! I gave a try to `textutil` but it works only for very simply formatted files.

Comment: The 'save as' property is 'maintain compatibility' and is a boolean. As implied, it ensures compatibility with Word 97-2004. Try removing all three words ('without maintain compatibility'). I'm using Word 2011. I don't know what has changed in newer versions and you don't state your version. FWIW, each code sample (original, and both 'paste.ee') compiles without issue for me. Finally, when I place 'new version' as an applescript within an automator service, and run it while MS Word is running, it creates .docx files from the .doc.

Comment: I'm happy that at least it works for you @CJK. I use MS Word version 16.39 (I updated the question with version details). When I compile the paste.ee version without `compatibility` it is ok, as it is when I remove `without maintain compatibility`. However, when I try to run them, both **versions** render a `Script Error -1721` and the Result pane shows me `error "" number -1721`. I looked it up and according to Apple's developer web page this error means: `The wrong number of arguments was detected.`

Comment: @CJK: would you mind explaining how you run the script on your side? What I mean by that is: do you save the file containing the script as `Script`, `Script bundle`, `Application`, or `Text`? Do you then drag-n-drop the `.doc` files on the script or app icon? How do you integrate the script in Automator (e.g., on my side Automator does not provide `service`)? Should it be too long or complicated, I would totally understand and I greatly appreciate what you already did.

Comment: What I did to integrate the script in Automator (I commented out `without maintain compatibility`, but I cannot seem to choose a folder, just multiple files):
1. Launch Automator
2. Select Workflow
3. Click Choose
4. Drag `Ask for Finer Items` to the Workflow pane
5. In `Type:` select `Files`
6. Check `Allow Multiple Selection`
7. Drag `Run AppleScript` to the Workflow pane
8. Drag `Ask for Finer Items` to the Workflow pane
9. Paste the script (be sure to remove all existing script)
10. Click `Run`

Comment: FYI, your question is about converting files, not converting a folder full of files. I created a Service in Automator, added a 'Run Applescript' action and replaced (all of) the default text with the code above. After saving, you will have a new Service. To use, launch Word, select a Word doc in Finder (or multiple), right-click and choose your new service. It should open your doc in Word and save it to the same folder as a docx. This is but one approach. NB I'm not CJK by the way. I'm just following along because it interests me.

Comment: I should add that the new service should be set to: Service receives selected 'files or folders' in 'Finder'.

Comment: @Mockman: sorry for the name confusion. Although my question was about bulk/batch file conversion, converting a folder full of files was not excluded (it would have been a "nice to have"). Thanks for the explanation of the Automator Service: I will try it out.

Comment: NP, I was just worried that it might make it more difficult to follow the thread. I should add that converting a folder full of files is possible. It adds some complexity however and since there's been a lot involved just in dealing directly with files, I thought it best to work towards that first. One of the nice things about Services is that you can apply a keyboard shortcut to them.

Comment: _"I gave a try to textutil but it works only for very simply formatted files."_ I guess I don't have a one-liner for you... Sorrrrry :(

Comment: @CJK: No problems. Thank you very much for all your advices and code.

Answer (score 1):

I made this script to replace .doc to .docx recursively, using Microsoft Word – just replace the paths:

```
-- Get the Files in Entire Contents of Folder by Extension, then Sort them (AsObjC)

use AppleScript version "2.4"
use framework "Foundation"
use scripting additions

property |⌘| : a reference to current application
property NSPredicate : a reference to NSPredicate of |⌘|
property NSFileManager : a reference to NSFileManager of |⌘|
property |NSURL| : a reference to |NSURL| of |⌘|
property NSMutableArray : a reference to NSMutableArray of |⌘|
property NSURLIsRegularFileKey : a reference to NSURLIsRegularFileKey of |⌘|
property NSSortDescriptor : a reference to NSSortDescriptor of |⌘|
property NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsPackageDescendants : a reference to 2
property NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles : a reference to 4

-- Change the source folder as appropriate.
set sourceFolder to (POSIX path of (path to downloads folder))
set sourceURL to |NSURL|'s URLWithString:sourceFolder

set fileManager to NSFileManager's |defaultManager|()
set fileKey to NSURLIsRegularFileKey
set searchOptions to (NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsPackageDescendants) + (NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles)

-- Get entire contents of folder, includung contents of subfolders, without packages and hidden files
set entireContents to (fileManager's enumeratorAtURL:(sourceURL) includingPropertiesForKeys:({fileKey}) options:(searchOptions) errorHandler:(missing value))'s allObjects()

-- Filter case-insensitively for items with "rar" extensions.
set thePredicate to NSPredicate's predicateWithFormat:("pathExtension ==[c] 'doc'")
set urlArray to entireContents's filteredArrayUsingPredicate:(thePredicate)

-- The result is probably just the files we want, but check for any folders among them while getting their paths.
set theFiles to NSMutableArray's new()
set AsObjCTrue to current application's NSNumber's numberWithBool:true
repeat with theURL in urlArray
    if ((theURL's getResourceValue:(reference) forKey:(fileKey) |error|:(missing value))'s end) is AsObjCTrue then
        tell theFiles to addObject:(theURL)
    end if
end repeat

-- Sort the remaining URLs on their paths.
set sortDescriptor to NSSortDescriptor's sortDescriptorWithKey:("path") ascending:(true) selector:("localizedStandardCompare:")
theFiles's sortUsingDescriptors:({sortDescriptor})

set theFiles to theFiles as list

-- Open the files in Microsoft Word.
-- Ensure Microsoft Word has full disk access on Mac OS.
repeat with theFile in theFiles
    tell application "Microsoft Word"
        activate
        open file theFile
        set activeDoc to active document
        -- Must be HFS path, POSIX will fail.
        -- Add the "x" for "docx".
        set newPath to ((POSIX path of theFile) & "x") as POSIX file
        log newPath
        save as activeDoc file name newPath file format format document
        close front document saving no
        -- tell application "Finder" to delete theFile
    end tell
end repeat
```